# Maximum update depth exceeded. React useEffect hooks cycle rerander

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to fix problem on site after previous developer. He use hooks and useEffect in app, but I did not work with that features earlier.
In his code he truing update app state with using async calls in App function.
I think that every state update initiate rerander and rerander initiate state update, but do not now how to fix it

```
const App = ({
  getLastEvents,
  getAllEvents,
  getStatistics,
  getWinners,
  auth: { isAuthenticate },
  getProfile,
}) => {
  const [isRender, setIsRender] = useState(false);
  useEffect(async () => {
    await getLastEvents();
    await getStatistics();
    await getAllEvents();
    await getWinners();
    setIsRender(true);
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticate) getProfile();
  }, [isAuthenticate]);
  return (...
```

I would very thankful if you can explain me how to fix it

Comment: useEffect need first parameter return a function or null, ur code async function return a promise

Comment: First, whenever a component is rendered, `useEffect`s within are called. Second, whenever state is changed (e.g. `isRender`), the component is rerendered. **If you then change state within a `useEffect` without any condition, you have an infinite loop.**

Comment: Narrow down your problem, get rid of your first effect entirely (the async one - effects can't be `async` anyway so that needs to be fixed) and see if you still have the same issue.